# how to refresh page in angular 2

Tags: angular, angular-ui-router

I have created one router link as below. This router link loads `ProductsStartComponent` and then this component loads several other components using ngif and not via navigation. Since below Product categories link is visible in all pages so if I am clicking on this link after reaching to some component of ngif , this is not taking me back on `ProductsStartComponent`.

As I am new to Angular , my understanding for this behavior is because all values/models are set and that's why it's not navigating. I suppose this can be achieved by refresh or reload of page but how to achieve that. Please advise.

In admin.component.html, router Link is defined for clicking.
returns

```
<li routerLinkActive="active"><a routerLink="categories"><p>Products Categories</p></a></li>
```

returns

In app-routing.module.ts, which component need to be loaded on clicking of router link

```
const appRoutes: Routes = [
{path: 'admin', component: AdminComponent, children: [
    { path: 'dashboard', component: AdminDashboardComponent },
    { path: 'sellers', component: AdminSellersComponent },
    { path: 'categories', component: ProductsStartComponent}
]}]
```

In product-start.component.html, this is being loaded on first click on router link. Now if I click on edit button and moved to other component and again if i click on product categories router link , nothing happen , I am expecting it to reset the page.

```
<div>
    <div *ngIf="!isChildProductClicked; else notClicked" >
       <app-admin-products (productId)="received($event)"></app-admin-products>
    </div>
    <ng-template #notClicked><app-child-products [selProdIndex]=productIndex></app-child-products></ng-template>
</div>
```

Comment: You mean that the routerlink dont work from other pages ?

Comment: Could you provide a bit more code illustrating your question? Are the other "pages" actually child components? In Angular a component is normally displayed either as a child component (using its selector) or as a routing target (routed via a routerLink or .navigate()).

Comment: @DeborahK yes I have displayed other components as selector

Comment: @ZAhmed added more contexts. Please have a look

Answer (score 77):

If you want to reload the page , you can easily go to your component then do :

```
location.reload();
```

Comment: The provider Location from @angular/common don't have a reload() function on angular 5+

Comment: it's pure javascript that reload the whole page not angular library.

Answer (score 38):

Just in case someone else encounters this problem. You need to call

```
window.location.reload()
```

And you cannot call this from a expression. If you want to call this from a click event you need to put this on a function:

```
(click)="realodPage()"
```

And simply define the function:

```
reloadPage() {
   window.location.reload();
}
```

If you are changing the route, it might not work because the click event seems to happen before the route changes. A very dirty solution is just to add a small delay

```
reloadPage() {
    setTimeout(()=>{
      window.location.reload();
    }, 100);
}
```

Comment: It wont do hard refresh and data will be loaded from cache. location.reload(true) was an option but it seems to be deprecated.

Answer (score 6):

> Updated

How to implement page refresh in Angular 2+ note this is done within your component:

```
location.reload();
```

Comment: Location from @angular/common  does not provide the reload function

Comment: Using location.reload() defeats the whole idea of SPA.

Comment: @valentine how to forece reload page from server and not from cache in SPA then ? sometimes it is required for use to have correct results.

Answer (score 4):

The simplest possible solution I found was:

In your markup:

```
<a [href]="location.path()">Reload</a>
```

and in your component typescript file:

```
constructor(
        private location: Location
  ) { }
```

Answer (score 2):

After saving or any operation, I have used the following code for reload the page

reloadCurrentRoute() {
let currentUrl = this.router.url;
this.router.navigateByUrl('/', {skipLocationChange: true}).then(() => {
this.router.navigate([currentUrl]);
});
}

Answer (score 1):

Without a bit more code ... its hard to say what's going on.

But if your code looks something like this:

```
<li routerLinkActive="active">
  <a [routerLink]="/categories"><p>Products Categories</p></a>
</li>
...
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
<myComponentA></myComponentA>
<myComponentB></myComponentB>
```

Then clicking on the router link will route to the categories route and display its template in the router outlet.

Hiding and showing the child components don't affect what is displayed in the router outlet.

So if you click the link again, the categories route is already displayed in the router outlet and it won't display/re-initialize again.

If you could be a bit more specific about what you are trying to do, we could provide more specific suggestions for you. :-)

Comment: I am trying to add more code and contexts but it's blocking me to save edits and asking me to add more contexts when I already i have added enough contexts in my edit :(

Comment: added more contexts. Please have a look

Answer (score 1):

Inside ngOnInit we can use location.reload() to reload the page

```
ngOnInit() {
    let username = 'Tom';
    if (username !== false && username !== undefined && username !== '' && username !== 'undefined') {
      this.username = username.toUpperCase();
    } else {
      location.reload();
    }
```

}

Answer (score 0):

window.location.reload() or just location.reload()

Answer (score 0):

location.reload()
reloads the full window [href].  Another way is to reload smoothly a page by going to another page, i.e **/tmppath/:p**, with the current path as a parameter

```
location.pathname
```

and then come back to the current component. That method may be suitable if you have a template or layout Component that contains other components.

Another way is also to call readily the initialization functions, i.e

```
this.ngAfterContentInit()
```

May it helps someone.
Thanks