# Angular | how to call a ngonit() method from another component

Tags: angular, angular4-router, angular4-httpclient

Here the scenario is that i have a header component where i have a selection box . on change of that selection i have to refresh the current page

example:

this seems not working for me

```
this.router.navigate([ document.location.pathname]);
```

Comment: check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45607077/how-to-refresh-page-in-angular-2

Comment: ngOninit is called only once when the component is initialised .

Comment: @PratapA.K not working for me

Comment: Use a shared service to communicate betwwen components: https://stackoverflow.com/a/52206772/1160794

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Refreshing the actual page is probably not what you want. I assume you just want to reload the data based on that selection. How do you know what is selected in the 1st place?

You should be using a common service that:

- selection box from header, on change, notifies that service that the selection changed
- whatever component cares, subscribes to the event exposed by that service and does whatever it wants with it (reload/etc.)

Comment: HI Andrew Thank you for the help and i got the concept . Is there any example you can point to  for more clarity

Comment: @MadhuNair Nothing better than the official documentation: https://angular.io/tutorial/toh-pt4